# javascript doesnt execute code after for

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, callback

I have created 2 functions in javascript, these functions are fired on click events, the problem is that after the `for` loops, alerts are not executed.

```js
function myfunc() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[i].style.color="red";
    }

    alert("alert 1"); //this should be executed after the for since it is part of the function code.
}

function myfunc2() {
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[j].style.color="navy";  
    }

    alert("alert 2"); //this should be executed after the for since it is part of the function code
}
```

```html
<h1 onClick="myfunc()">primo h1</h1>
<h1 onClick="myfunc2();">secondo h1</h1>
```

Comment: Are the bodies of the loop executed? the attribute is usually written `onclick` (without a capital letter), I don't know if the case is important.

Comment: Are there at least four `<h1>`s for each function?

Comment: Changing the length as @MaxStarkenburg suggested, works fine. Get the length using something like: `var h1Len = document.getElementsByTagName("h1").length;` and use insted of the hardcoded number

Answer (score 1):

You need to check how many `h1` tags there are in the DOM before applying new style attributes. You are effectively trying to make changes to `undefined`.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

function myfunc() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.color="red";
    }

    alert("alert 1"); //this should be executed after the for since it is part of the function code.
}

function myfunc2() {
    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
        elements[j].style.color="navy";
    }

    alert("alert 2"); //this should be executed after the for since it is part of the function code
}
```

```html
<h1 onClick="myfunc()">primo h1</h1>
<h1 onClick="myfunc2();">secondo h1</h1>
```

Comment: why would you store the DOM node on a `elements` var and call from the DOM once again inside the for-loop instead of using your `elements`

Comment: It was a quick copy from the original question. Corrected.